# C# navegador web, como obtener la direccion web actual?

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Me han pedido crear un navegador web en C#, lo cual si nos mantenemos en lo basico es bastante simple, pero, al visitar varias paginas web y presionar el boton hacia atras, no me pone la direccion web en el textbox del navegador.

Hice que el boton "hacia atras" tenga el siguiente codigo

```
textBox.Text = webBrowser.Url.ToString();
```

pero, me trae la direccion web de la pagina anterior, no de la que estoy.

Hay alguna forma de poder obtener la direccion web de la pagina actual?

muchas gracias

Answer (score 1):

La funcion que se puede utilizar es obtener la url absoluta

```
string url = "";
url = webBrowser.Url.AbsoluteUri;
```

Comment: Gracias por la solucion, pero, me hace exactamente lo mismo que la que expuse. Lo que quiero es que al darle al boton de atras, el textBox me tome el nombre de la web actual en la que estoy y no de la que estaba. Con la funcion goBack() que es la que me simplifica el codigo del boton, pense que habia una forma de saber cual es la direccion web que hay, ya que la debe de guardar en algun lugar. Muchas gracias por la sugerencia, aprendi a hacerlo de otra forma

Comment: Que bueno que lo encontraras y lo siento por no ser la solucion